# Stop MySQL from selecting empty rows in query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to query my database and show the user even if the user has numerous profiles.

```
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
| id | name  |  phone  |       email        |
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|  1 | bob   | 5555555 | bob@gmail.com      |
|  2 | John  | 6666666 | john@gmail.com     |
|  3 | robert| 5555555 | bobswork@gmail.com |
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

I am doing this currently with this query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM entires a INNER JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM entires WHERE id='1') b
    ON (a.phone=b.phone
    OR a.email=b.email
 );
```

Which works really well, however it breaks the whole system if two fields are blank. Then it just matches everything and I get the results of every entry with missing details. How can I prevent this from showing blank matches?

Comment: Are the fields blank or NULL? Are they consistently blank or are some single spaces, others empty?

Comment: Are you talking about when id=1 and name is blank and email is blank or something else?

Comment: @tadman All data is not required, I have many more fields than just email and phone - I just trimmed for the example.

Comment: I'm asking if these "blank" values are literally NULL or if they're something like an empty string, or a bunch of spaces.

Comment: @tadman They are null.

Comment: `NULL=NULL` is `NULL` so they won't match that way. `""=""` though.

Comment: @tadman I don't follow, perhaps my table structure is to blame? Should I make the default value NULL?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if `a.phone` is `NULL` and `b.phone` is also `NULL` then `a.phone=b.phone` fails to match, `NULL=NULL` doesn't test as truthful. I'd check that you have `NULL` for sure, and not a bunch of empty strings that coincidentally match. You may need to clean up your data and/or change the default if it's set to something like `DEFAULT ''`.

Comment: @tadman I think they are empty strings then. What is the difference?

Comment: Empty strings do match, but `NULL` will not. It's a big difference when doing a `JOIN` like this.

Comment: @tony, your query is working. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=992b33d04c71b381caf8cd65cf2a5a0e)  Show an example of data that breaks the result.

Answer (score 0):

For mySql use IFNULL() function in join condition.
Ex: `IFNULL(a.phone, '1111') = IFNULL(b.phone, '1111') or  IFNULL(a.email, 'a@a.com') = IFNULL(b.email, 'a@a.com')`.

IFNULL() function takes the second argument value if the first argument is NULL. In above case condition will be true if both the records having NULL value or same value. In case you want the condition to fail if both values are NULL, then take different value in second argument for IFNULL() function.

Comment: however it breaks the whole system if two fields are blank. Then it just matches everything and I get the results of every entry with missing details. Can you show which fields you made blank from your data.